# Hide delete button from table, after 3 days

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php table that calls records from a mysql database.

```
DATE | CUSTOMER | QUANTITY | ACTIONS
```

Every row have in column ACTION  a delete button :

```
<a href="purchases.php?order_id=' . $row['id'] . '" onClick="return confirm(\''. $LANG['del_purchase'] .'\');">
<img src="images/delete.png" width="16" height="16" title="delete" style="margin:1px;"/>`
```

Is there a way to hide the delete button after 3 days from the date in column DATE?

many thanks

Comment: Put an `if` condition around it and don't render if the date you want expired.

Comment: In addition to @El_Vanja , make sure to have purchases.php not allow the deletion aswell. If someone directly access that link, it shouldn't delete the item aswell

Comment: I second what @Timberman said. Though, it would be a wise decision to switch deleting over to a `post` operation. Much safer than `get`.

Comment: @El_Vanja How exacly is that safer? You can simply send a post request using chrome / postman aswell. Its only a bit more trouble than a normal get request.

Comment: @Timberman My bad for not being precise. I meant it as a general practice - a `post` can't be accidentally triggered by visiting a link or be triggered by a bot. It's safer in terms of your regular user (Postman is far beyond the regular user's reach), you automatically eliminate weak points in your system. I agree that regardless of the method you need to place boundaries in the code itself where applicable (such as the three day margin in this question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime($row['date']);
$checkDate = new DateTime('-3 days');
if ($date > $checkDate) {
?>
    <a href="purchases.php?order_id=' . $row['id'] . '" onClick="return confirm(\''. $LANG['del_purchase'] .'\');">
        <img src="images/delete.png" width="16" height="16" title="delete" style="margin:1px;"/>
    </a>
<?php
}
?>
```

This creates a `DateTime` object for *your* date and one for 3 days ago from now, then checks whether your date is greater (after) it, and only shows the delete button based on the result of that condition.

Obviously you'll need to be sure to use your column name instead of `date`, and make sure it is a format that [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) understands.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all for answers!

Ok the code works but...in your opinion why my table has lost the style and the chance to sort the column?

This is only for an intranet project, it doesn’t matter if it’s not very safe.

```
<?php 
                  
                   echo '<table id="Data" width="100%" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">';
                    echo '<thead>';
                    // echo '<th style="width: 19px;" class="default"></th>';
                    echo '<th class="default" style="width: 60px; text-align: left;">'. $LANG['date'] .'</th>';
                    echo '<th style="width: 90px; text-align: center;" class="default">'. $LANG['pr_code'] .'</th>';
                    echo '<th style="width: 65px; text-align: center;" class="default">'. $LANG['quantity'] .'</th>';
                    echo '<th style="width: 40px; padding-right: 5px; padding-left: 5px; text-align: center;" class="default" id="task">'. $LANG['actions'] .'</th>';
                    echo '</thead>';
                    echo '<tbody>';
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {

                        $orderdate = strtotime($row['or_date']);
            $fdate = strftime("%d/%m/%Y", $orderdate);
            $originalDatePlusThreeDays = strtotime($row['or_date'].'+3 days');
                        echo '<tr>';
                        echo '<td class="txtLeft">' . $fdate . '</td>';
                        echo '<td class="txtCenter">' . $row['pr_code'] . '</td>';
                        echo '<td class="txtCenter">' . $row['or_quantity'] . '</td>';
                        echo '</td>';
                        if($originalDatePlusThreeDays >= strtotime('now')) {
                        
                          echo '<td class="txtCenter" id="task1">
                             
                            
                            <a href="purchases.php?order_id=' . $row['id'] . '" onClick="return confirm(\''. $LANG['alert_purchase_del'] .'\');">
                            <img src="images/delete.png" width="16" height="16" title="delete purchase" style="margin:1px;"/>
                            </a>
                            
                            </td>'; 
                            }
                        echo '</tr>';
                    } 
                    
                    echo '</tbody>';
                    echo '</table>';
                    
                 
                ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$originalDatePlusThreeDays = strtotime( <<< your date from DB >>> . '+3 days');
...
if ($originalDatePlusThreeDays <= strtotime('now')) {
    echo 'your button';
}
```

Comment: This comes with a caveat - if `strtotime` doesn't accept the format of the date, it will fail. Also, you're missing quotes around "now".

Comment: Many thanks!
Ok the code works but...in your opinion why my table has lost the style and the chance to sort the column?

Comment: I think it lost the style because, if there's no button, you print there the other data. You should add `else { echo 'empty cell' }` or something like that.

Comment: Thank you very much! I resolve with: a "display:none" style.